# Localized COLLATE on a SQLite string comparison

Tags: unicode, sqlite

I want to compare two strings in a SQLite DB without caring for the accents and the case. I mean "Événement" should be equal to "evenèment".

On Debian Wheezy, the SQLite package doesn't provide ICU. So I compiled the official SQLite package (version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05) with contains an ICU module. Now, I do have a better Unicode support (the original`lower()` applied only to ASCII chars, now it works on other letters). But I can't manage to apply a collation to a comparison.

```
SELECT icu_load_collation('fr_FR', 'FRENCH');
SELECT 'événement' COLLATE FRENCH = 'evenement';
-- 0 (should be 1)
SELECT 'Événement' COLLATE FRENCH = 'événement';
-- 0 (should be 1 if collation was case-insensitive)
SELECT lower('Événement') = 'événement';
-- 1 (at least lower() works as expected with Unicode strings)
```

The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) confirms that this is the right way to apply a collation. I think the [documentation of this ICU extension](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt) is a bit light (few examples, nothing on case sensitivity for collations).

I don't understand why the `COLLATE` operator has no effect in my example above. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I took me hours to understand the situation... The way the ICU collations are defined in SQLite has (almost) no incidence on comparisons. An exception being, according to the ICU, Hebrew texts with cantillation marks. This is the default behavior of the ICU library's collation. With SQLite, `LIKE` becomes case-insensitive when ICU is loaded, but normalization of the accentuated letters can't be attained this way.

I finally understood that what I needed was to set the
[strength](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization#TOC-Default-Options)
of the collation to the
[primary level](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/concepts)
instead of the default tertiary level.

I found no way to set this through the locale
(e.g several variants of `SELECT icu_load_collation('fr_FR,strength=0', 'french')` were useless).
So the only solution was to patch the code of SQLite.
It was easy thanks to the `ucol_setStrength()` function
in the [ICU API](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html).

The minimal change is a one-line patch: add the line `ucol_setStrength(pUCollator, 0);` after `pUCollator = ucol_open(zLocale, &status);` in the function `icuLoadCollation()`.
For a backwards-compatible change, I added an optional third parameter to `icu_load_collation()` that sets the strength:
0 for default, 1 for primary, etc. up to 4-quaternary.
See the [diff](https://gist.github.com/mytskine/5028755).

At last I have what I wanted:

```
SELECT icu_load_collation('fr_FR', 'french_ci', 1); -- collation with strength=primary
SELECT 'Événement' COLLATE french_ci = 'evenèment';
-- 1
```